# Seeking data model for land use?

Tags: references, land-use, data-model

Does anyone know where I can find a data model for land use?

I know about data models available on [Esri Support site](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/datamodel).

Are there any other resources?

Comment: What aspects are you looking at? Transportation, demographics or other? There are quite a few nice models which can be accessed through the pages at CSISS (http://www.csiss.org/GISPopSci/research/links.php) which deal with more on demographic segregation.

Answer (score 2):

The Infrastructure for Spatial Information in Europe (INSPIRE) has a [land use data model](http://inspire.jrc.ec.europa.eu/documents/Data_Specifications/INSPIRE_DataSpecification_LU_v3.0rc3.pdf). Here's an [overview](http://www.agiv.be/gis/getDownload.ashx?id=1226).

Here's a [comparison between the Plan4all and INSPIRE Land Use Data Model](http://www.plan4all.eu/simplecms/?menuID=29&articleID=103&action=article&presenter=ArticleDetail). Can't find a document about just the Plan4all data model though, will post it here if I do find it.

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of sources.  For example: [here](http://edc2.usgs.gov/glcc/globdoc2_0.php) is a global 1km land cover data set, and another source [here](http://glcf.umd.edu/data/landcover/).  For Europe you can try searching for the [CORINE](http://www.eea.europa.eu/publications/COR0-landcover) project.

The global data sets tend to be quite course.  These sites are just for starters.  You may get a more targeted response if you refine your question to state what area you are interested in.

Comment: -1 Those are great land cover datasets. Unfortunately, the OP asked for land use data models.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, what area are you working on?  There is a land cover dataset for Australia located [here](http://www.ga.gov.au/earth-observation/landcover.html).  Resolution is about 250m.

I know land cover is different to land use, and Australia's land cover varies widely and is different to many other part of the world, but it might give you some useful reference.  There's a link to the Technical Report on that page.

Comment: Sorry, the question was for a data model, not datasets.